# waitOnReceipt function doesn't work in solidity, running on SuperBlocks

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Running on https://studio.superblocks.com/ trying to make a a fun game in Solidity. the problem happens when I call waitfor receipt inside the "addKity" function. Any ideas why? I suspect it could be because of a technical issue in superblocks but could very well be because of a coding error I have.

It reaches the "heres" alert but doesn't reach alert("4");

Please let me know your thoughts!

```
waitForReceipt(txHash, function(receipt){
```

Javascript File

```
(function (Contract) {
    var web3_instance;
    var instance;
    var accounts;

    function init(cb) {
        web3_instance = new Web3(
            (window.web3 && window.web3.currentProvider) ||
            new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(Contract.endpoint));

        accounts = web3.eth.accounts;


        var contract_interface = web3_instance.eth.contract(Contract.abi);


        instance = contract_interface.at(Contract.address);
        cb();
    }

function waitForReceipt(hash, cb) {
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash, function (err, receipt) {
    if (err) {
    error(err);
    }

    if (receipt !== null) {
    // Transaction went through
    if (cb) {
        cb(receipt);
    }
    } else {
    // Try again in 1 second
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        waitForReceipt(hash, cb);
    }, 1000);
    }
});
}





    function addKitty(){

    //  var KittyName = "he"; //$("#kittyName").val();
    //  var KittyPrice = 5;//parseInt($("#kittyPrice").val());


const transactionObject = {
from: "0x95c2332b26bb22153a689ae619d81a6c59e0a804",
gas: "1000000",
gasPrice: "1000000",
value:"1000"
};

    instance.addNewKitty.sendTransaction("sdad",5, transactionObject, (error, result) => { 

    if(error){
        alert(error);
        alert("2");
        }
        else{
            alert("heres");


            waitForReceipt(txHash, function(receipt){
                alert("4");
            //   if(receipt.status === "0x1"){

            //     alert("got receipt");
            //   }
            //   else{
            //       alert("5");
            //     alert("receipt status fail");
            //   }
            });
        }
    })

    }









    // function getMessage(cb) {
    //     instance.message(function (error, result) {
    //         cb(error, result);
    //     });
    // }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        init(function () {
            // getMessage(function (error, result) {
            //     if (error) {
            //         console.error("Could not get article:", error);
            //         return;
            //     }
            //     $('#message').append(result);
            // });
            $("#addKitty").click(function(){

            addKitty();
        })

        });
    });
})(Contracts['CryptoKitties']);
```

Solidity file

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.21;


contract CryptoKitties  {

    address public owner;

    struct CKitties{
        string name;
        uint price;
    }


function CryptoKitties() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}




    mapping (address => uint) kittytoUser;  
    CKitties[] kitties;

    event NewCryptoKitty(address owner, string name, uint price); 

    modifier cost (uint minCost){
        require(msg.value>= minCost && minCost >=0);
        _;
    }

function addNewKitty(string newName, uint newPrice) public payable cost(5000) {
    address sender = msg.sender;
    uint place =  kitties.push(CKitties(newName,newPrice));
    kittytoUser[sender] = place;
    emit NewCryptoKitty(sender, newName, newPrice);

}

function kill() public  onlyOwner{
    selfdestruct(owner);
}



function getName() public view returns (string){
        address sender = msg.sender;
        uint index = kittytoUser[sender]-1;
        return kitties[index].name;
}

function setName(string newName) public{
    address sender = msg.sender;
        uint index = kittytoUser[sender]-1;
        kitties[index].name = newName;
}

function getBalance() public view returns (uint){
    return address(this).balance;
}




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `waitForReceipt` function is getting called passing an undefined value `txHash`. In that context, it should be `result` instead (the value coming from the callback that activated that call, triggered by `sendTransaction`).
That change will make `waitForReceipt` call work.

The other problem is that you have the `web3` variable named as `web3_instance`, but you still refer to it as `web3`.
Considering that, inside `waitForReceipt`, you are still referencing to it as `web3.eth...`, while the correct call in that context would be: `web3_instance.eth.getTransactionReceipt...`.
With that fixed, `alert("4")` will get called as intended.

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much. I'm still such a beginner though that now I ran into another issue, the receipt returns null. See issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814569/solidity-web3-transaction-receipt-returns-null